# How to implements 2 level bash TAB auto-completion

Tags: bash, bash-completion

Here is a test.sh and I want it has a auto-completion function
by add this:

```
complete -W "1level 2level" test.sh
```

into .bashrs

when I input `test.sh 1` and press [TAB] key, it will help me auto fill 1level .
But now I want it help me auto complete another column like:

```
test.sh 1level sec[TAB]
```

I hope I can customize the second and third and Nth column, I had tried this:

```
complete -W "secOption1 secOption2" test.sh 1level
complete -W "secOption1 secOption2" test.sh 2level
```

but it did't work

Comment: I was looking for a solution of a similar problem (extended to arbitrary number of levels) with keywords for each level being sourced from some config or online system. I couldn't help myself from creating this: https://github.com/uvsmtid/argrelay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own auto-completion function. For example:

```
[STEP 100] $ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.30(1)-release
[STEP 101] $ cat compspec
function _compgen_foo
{   
    local cmd=$1 cur=$2 pre=$3

    if [[ $pre == "$cmd" ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "pos1a-example pos1b-example" -- "$cur") )
        return
    fi

    if [[ $pre == pos1* ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "pos2a-example pos2b-example" -- "$cur") )
        return
    fi
}

complete -F _compgen_foo foo
[STEP 102] $ source ./compspec
[STEP 103] $ foo <TAB>
[STEP 103] $ foo pos1
[STEP 103] $ foo pos1<TAB><TAB>
pos1a-example  pos1b-example
[STEP 103] $ foo pos1a<TAB>
[STEP 103] $ foo pos1a-example␣
[STEP 103] $ foo pos1a-example <TAB>
[STEP 103] $ foo pos1a-example pos2
[STEP 103] $ foo pos1a-example pos2<TAB><TAB>
pos2a-example  pos2b-example
[STEP 103] $ foo pos1a-example pos2
[STEP 103] $ foo pos1a-example pos2b<TAB>
[STEP 103] $ foo pos1a-example pos2b-example␣
[STEP 103] $ foo pos1a-example pos2b-example <CR>
bash: foo: command not found
[STEP 104] $
```

For more information please see [Programmable Completion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html#Programmable-Completion) in Bash's manual.

Comment: Could you pls explan --"$cur" means ? I didn't find it in the manual

Comment: @JasonYang: You can find the information in the page [Programmable Completion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html#Programmable-Completion). It's not long.

Comment: Great! Can you explain why this did't work ?                                                           if [[ $pre == *server ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "\'grep" -- "$cur") )
        return
    fi

    if [[ $pre == *rep ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "aaa  bbb" -- "$cur") )
        return
    fi                                                                                                                    $pre == *rep will never return true.  but my command looks like: test 'grep.

Comment: It's not easy to write code in SO's comments. You can ask a new question.